# FastAPI Pydantic, create a model field that can assign users to a project and collect their IDs

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, pydantic

## **ISSUE:**

I am currently facing difficulties in creating a model field that allows me to assign users to a particular project and collect their corresponding user IDs when they are assigned. The specific format of the return value, whether it is a list of user objects or a list of user IDs, is not critical at this point.

## **GOAL**

My main objective is to establish a mechanism for associating users with a project and capturing their IDs for reference. The exact format of the return value can be adjusted later based on the specific requirements and needs of the project.

**Models.py: **

```
import sqlalchemy as _sql
import sqlalchemy.orm as _orm
import passlib.hash as _hash
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, DateTime, ForeignKey, Enum
from datetime import datetime
import database as _database
from database import engine
import enum


class User(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    access = Column(String, nullable=False)
    avatar_url = Column(String)

    projects = _orm.relationship("Project", back_populates="owner", uselist=True)
    tasks = _orm.relationship("Task", back_populates="assigned_user", uselist=True)
    assigned_projects = _orm.relationship("Project", back_populates="assigned_users",uselist=True)

    def verify_password(self, password: str):
        return _hash.bcrypt.verify(password, self.password)

# Define the Project model


class Project(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "projects"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String)
    status = Column(String)
    due_date = Column(DateTime)
    created_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))

    assigned_users = _orm.relationship("User", back_populates="assigned_projects", uselist=True)
    owner = _orm.relationship("User", back_populates="projects", uselist=False)
    tasks = _orm.relationship("Task", back_populates="project", uselist=True)
```

**
Schemas.py:**

```
import pydantic as _pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel as _BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.types import StrictStr
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional

# USERS


class _UserBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    access: str
    avatar_url: Optional[str] | None = None


class UserCreate(_UserBase):
    password: str


class User(_UserBase):
    id: int
    password: str
    assigned_projects: List["Project"] = []
    tasks: List["Task"] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

# PROJECTS


class _ProjectBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str
    status: str
    due_date: Optional[datetime]
    assigned_users: Optional[List[int]] = []


class ProjectCreate(_ProjectBase):
    pass


class Project(_ProjectBase):
    id: int
    owner_id: int
    created_date: datetime
    updated_date: datetime
    owner: User = None
    tasks: List["Task"] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

and in **services.py** update_projects function:

```
async def _project_selector(project_id: int, db: _orm.Session):
    project = db.query(_models.Project).filter(
        _models.Project.id == project_id).first()
    if project is None:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=404, detail="Project not found")
    return project


async def update_project(db: _orm.Session, project: _schemas.ProjectCreate, project_id: int):
    db_project = await _project_selector(db=db, project_id=project_id)
    try:
        db_project.name = project.name
        db_project.description = project.description
        db_project.status = project.status
        db_project.due_date = project.due_date
        db_project.assigned_users = project.assigned_users
        db_project.updated_date = datetime.utcnow()

        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_project)
        return _schemas.Project.from_orm(db_project)
    except:
        return {"message": "Failed to update project"}
```

**main.py: **

```
@app.put('/api/projects/{project_id}', status_code=200, description="Update project by id")
async def update_project(project_id: int, project: _schemas.ProjectCreate, db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db)):
    await _services.update_project(db=db, project=project, project_id=project_id)
    return {"message": f"Successfully updated project with id: {project_id}", "project": project}
```

## **What I have tried: **

I have made changes to the code by converting assigned_users to a column of type `ARRAY()` and updating the Schemas accordingly. Previously, assigned_users was of type `Optional[List[User]] = []`, but now it has been changed to `Optional[List[int]] = []`.

By using a list of user IDs instead of the full user objects, I aim to reduce the payload and minimize the load on the system, especially when dealing with projects that have a large number of users. Considering that users may have additional fields such as logs or images, transmitting the full user objects can significantly increase the payload size.

Ultimately, whether the schema returns a list of user IDs or the complete user objects does not significantly impact the outcome.

Additionally, I am uncertain whether assigned_projects should remain in object form or if it should be changed to a list of project IDs. Similarly, I am unsure about the owner field, which is intended to represent the project's admin/manager overseeing the project, while assigned_users refer to the development team responsible for its execution.